# How to insulate this portion of split AC Pipe?

Tags: insulation, air-conditioning, central-air

I bought a new Hitachi split AC lately which isn't cooling as much I was expecting.

I checked for leaks/bad installation and found this.

(This is connection point of external pipe and pipe which came inside split)

[image]

As per what I have studied, it's important to insulate the big pipe at least.

I have two questions:

1. As this part is next to the split section aka inside a room, to what percentage can it affect cooling?
2. What should I use to insulate this joint? Would Aluminum Tape do? There are very limited options available here in India. I found this [aluminum foil shielding tape](http://www.ebay.in/itm/1-PCS-Aluminum-Foil-EMI-Shielding-Shield-Tape-48mmx1M-/360346848962) on eBay. Would this do the job?

Comment: The amount of heat loss (or rather, gain) you'll experience on this tiny joint is miniscule.  It is much more likely that your problem with not-enough-cooling lies elsewhere in the system.

Comment: OK. That answer the first question. Also, please guide if the given aluminium tape would do the insulation work?

Comment: The larger pipe is the suction line, which is taking the heat out of your house. Adding a bit more heat won't make much difference, since it'll just be dumped outside anyway.  The small liquid line should be hotter than the ambient air, so you don't have to worry about that line getting heated either. The suction line is commonly insulated to reduce condensation on the line, since it's typically below the dew point during normal operation. The liquid line may also be insulated to avoid people touching it, but is often left uninsulated.

Comment: How many square meters are you trying to cool and how many BTU's is the split ac unit? Try as well to measure the temperature just outside the exit of the a/c ( inside unit ). I think the rule of thumb is that for non problematic installations you should read definitely below 10 or better below 9 Celsius degrees.